# Poetry install packages asynchronously

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-poetry

I am using poetry with docker and it seems my deployment process is significantly slowed down by poetry downloading the packages synchronously. Is there a way to download the packages asynchronously?

Comment: asynchronous process -> It's not faster, it just doesn't waste time.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but still... have you looked into better caching (either on the side of pip/poetry or docker)? I believe you should not have to download much once you have already reached the deployment stage.

Answer (score 0):

Poetry is a young project with not much performance tuning done compared to pip. If performance is important to you, you can use something like:

```
poetry export --without-hashes -f requirements.txt | pip install -r /dev/stdin
```

This will export the requirements from poetry and install them via pip. Note that you loose the security hash checks while keeping poetrys smart dependency resolution and version pinning. Note that not even pip can download packages in parallel (https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/825), but still is significantly faster.